# Multiple Crop Sizes in Laravel Filament

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

In my project, I both need a square-size preview image and larger rectangle image.

When I upload image with Filament, I can crop image with the following code. What I wonder, is it possible to have more than one cropped image (or save the original file)?

```
 FileUpload::make('image')
     ...
     ->imageCropAspectRatio('1:1')
     ->imageResizeTargetWidth('400')
     ->imageResizeTargetHeight('400')
     ->image()
     ->imageEditor()
```